# How to detect touch point in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch-event

I need to be able to detect where in the window a drag event on a UIScrollView occurs. I can't find any scroll view delegate methods that will do this?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the underlying `UIPanGestureRecognizer` from your scroll view by its `panGestureRecognizer` property. Once you have that, you can add your class as a target with the `addTarget:action:` method.

In your handler, you can get the touches from the gesture recognizer.